# Django - Can I create a global variable that can be accessed/manipulated from different functions in different files?

Tags: django, global-variables, argument-passing

I'm trying to figure out a way I can avoid passing so many arguments to functions in my app. I'm using different databases for each table, so joining is not possible, so I need to create a primary key dictionary that has the objects I need for subsequent functions. I do this to make only two queries.

My example is below. Please note how I have to pass in the `people_ref` reference dictionary to each deform function. What I would like to do is set some sort of global `people_ref` variable that can be accessed from anywhere. That way I could just dump the People.in_bulk() response to the global pool, and then access it directly from inside the deform functions without having to pass in the reference. Is there a way to do that?

What I want to call:

```
>>> myapp.models.make_crazy_books([1,2,3])
```

From myapp/models.py:

```
import itertools
from django.db import models
from myapp.utils import deform

class People(models.Model):
    born = model.DateField()

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(People, related_name='author_set')
    editor = models.ForeignKey(People, related_name='editor_set')
    last_edition = model.DateField()

def make_crazy_books(book_ids):
    book_list = Book.objects.using("db1").filter(id__in=book_ids) #Query here, db1

    people_list = ((b.author_id, b.editor_id) for b in book_list)
    people_ids = set(itertools.chain(*people_list))
    people_ref = People.objects.using("db2").in_bulk(people_ids) #Query here, db2

    #Would like to not have to send people_ref to each function
    book_list = deform.deform_edition(book_list, people_ref)
    book_list = deform.deform_author(book_list, people_ref)
    """ ... do some other deforming functions """

    return book_list
```

From mayapp/utils/deform.py:

```
def deform_edition(book_list, people_ref):
    for book in book_list:
        author = people_ref[book.author_id] #Change to global lookup?
        b.last_edition = author.born
    return book_list

def deform_author(book_list, people_ref):
    for book in book_list:
        editor = people_ref[book.editor_id] #Change to global lookup?
        b.author = editor
    return book_list
```

I would try using Django's caching functionality, but with multiple threads running, the cached reference dictionary can be read/overwritten by other simultaneous requests.

EDIT: Perhaps [local-memory caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#local-memory-caching) would work since it's thread safe?

Comment: LocMem caching is thread-safe, but it comes at the cost of performance. The docs clearly say that it's *not* a good choice for production environments. Globals are always a bad idea, I consider it a *feature* of Python/Django that their use is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, sharing data between a group of related functions is what OOP is for - define a class that contains the functions (as methods), then instantiate the class with the particular data.

In this case though there is a class already associated with the data - it's a QuerySet of People objects. So you could define a custom QuerySet subclass for People that contains the `deform` methods - unfortunately in Django to get that to work you also need to define a custom Manager, overriding `get_query_set` to return your QuerySet subclass.